# Is there any TFS environment variable to know the "bin" folder path in build definition?

Tags: powershell, build, environment-variables, tfsbuild, bin

For example, there is `TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY` environment in TFS which we can use in Post-build Powershell scripts to know the sources directory (where TFS has dumped the source code at build server during build).
That means, this can return us something like - "C:\Builds\3\MyProject\MyApplication.UAT\src"

Now, I would like to know the location of "bin" folder (which usually will be - "C:\Builds\3\MyProject\MyApplication.UAT\bin" in above case). I can always predict that using string replacements, but I would prefer to use Environment variable if there is any.

Do anyone know the environment variable to get the "bin" folder path in build definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found it myself from a bit more research on MSDN..

there is an environment variable for this in TFS named as - "TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY". This variable can be used in TFS build (post-build or pre-build powershell scripts) to know the location of build folder on build server

Comment: Are u still using this variable? I'm getting `The term 'TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`.

Answer (score 1):

TargetDir should be available after the msbuild task as been run.

Will give you something like the following for an console applicaiton.

```
$(TargetDir)    "C:\\Playground\\Sln\\prj\\bin\\Debug\\"
```

or something like this for a web application.

```
$(TargetDir)    "C:\\Playground\\sln\\prj\\bin\\"
```

This isn't an environment variable but rather an msbuild variable which I belive is what you are after.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was actually looking for environment variable for TFS build processes. check the answer i have posted. However, my upvote for your attempt, and an answer which is true if I see in the context of solution build in Visual Studio.